# Absolute URL in a Link with TinymceBundle and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, tinymce

I have installed [TinymceBundle](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle) in my Symfony 2.8 project and it worked. But if I use it to send an email and bundle generate relative urls.

I tried

```
{{ tinymce_init({
    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false,
    convert_urls : true,})}}
```

But this didn't work.

Can you help me ?

Following is my configuration :

```
stfalcon_tinymce:

        selector: ".tinymce"
        # Get current language from the parameters.ini
        language: %locale%
        # Custom buttons
        tinymce_buttons:
            stfalcon: # Id of the first button
                title: "Stfalcon"
                image: "http://stfalcon.com/favicon.ico"
        theme:
            # Simple theme: same as default theme
            simple: ~
            # Advanced theme with almost all enabled plugins
            advanced:
                 plugins:
                     - "advlist lists link image charmap print preview hr pagebreak"
                     - "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"
                     - "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality"
                     - "emoticons paste textcolor"
                 toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
                 toolbar2: "print preview | forecolor backcolor emoticons"
```

Comment: Are you using a bundle to use TinyMCE? If so, please let us know which one. If not, what is the `tinymce_init` macro doing?

Comment: That's how TinyMCE is integrate to Symfony2 project (in Twig view).
https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle

This macro get ressources files.

Answer (score 0):

I find where is my problem.

I use :

```
 {{ tinymce_init({
    relative_urls : false,
    remove_script_host : false,
    convert_urls : true,})}}
```

to add absolute link, but this have to be in config.yml like this :

```
stfalcon_tinymce:

        selector: ".tinymce"
        # Get current language from the parameters.ini
        language: %locale%
        # Custom buttons
        tinymce_buttons:
            stfalcon: # Id of the first button
                title: "Stfalcon"
                image: "http://stfalcon.com/favicon.ico"
        theme:
            # Simple theme: same as default theme
            simple: ~
            # Advanced theme with almost all enabled plugins
            advanced:
                 relative_urls: false
                 remove_script_host : false
                 convert_urls : true
                 plugins:
                     - "advlist lists link image charmap print preview hr pagebreak"
                     - "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen"
                     - "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality"
                     - "emoticons paste textcolor"
                 toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
                 toolbar2: "print preview | forecolor backcolor emoticons"
```